# How do I rewrite httpd-vhosts.conf to allow SSL connections to a private web-server?

Tags: macos, apache, ssl

I am running Apache 2.4.34 (Unix) on a mid-2012 Mac mini running Mac OS 10.14.6 and I'm using this machine as a personal web-server.

When I uncomment "#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf " in httpd.conf, my browser tells me that it can't connect to the server, i.e. my Mac mini, as neither "localhost" nor using the domain name "www.ocetacea.net".

I've followed

https://www.ssl.com/how-to/csr-generation-in-macos-keychain-access/

to install my SSL certificates and

https://www.ssl.com/how-to/ssl-tls-installation-macos-mojave/#apache

to modify httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf.

My /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf currently looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ServerName ocetacea.net
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ocetacea.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/ocetacea.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/private/etc/apache2/ocetacea_bundle.crt"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    ServerName ocetacea.net
    SSLEngine on                                                                                             
    SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ocetacea.crt"                                                   
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/ocetacea.key"                                                
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/private/etc/apache2/ocetacea_bundle.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

> sudo apachectl configtest

results in:

> Syntax OK

and

> sudo apachectl -k restart

appears to do what I want, i.e. start the server.

My concern is that I didn't install the SSL certificates correctly.

> /private/etc/apache2/ocetacea.crt

begins with

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

and ends with

> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

while

> /private/etc/apache2/ocetacea.key

starts with:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

and ends with

> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

and

> /private/etc/apache2/ocetacea_bundle.crt

begins with:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

and ends with:

> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

which is not what I would expect--I would expect one of these three files to start with something like

> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

and end with

> -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY----

But this is my first time trying to set up a secured server, so I really don't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My system.log reads:

The system log repeats the following:

> Aug 14 18:40:55 jnorrisMM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
>
> Aug 14 18:41:06 jnorrisMM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd[18660]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
>
> Aug 14 18:41:06 jnorrisMM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
>
> Aug 14 18:41:16 jnorrisMM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd[18667]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

Comment: The filenames and extensions do not really matter. They are just a convenience for humans. However, by its name, `ocetacea_bundle.crt` should be a sequence of certificates and should not contain any key, private or public. Ask the company where you bought the certificate to help you and have the proper bundle file.

Comment: Patrick,

I've made sure that >ocetacea_bundle.crt is the bundle and not a key and I'm still having the same results.

But thanks for letting me know this was a problem.

Comment: You say "and /private/etc/apache2/ocetacea_bundle.crt begins with: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and I say that this is wrong just based on the assumption that for human convenience a file called "bundle.crt" should contain a list of certificates, so things starting with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and ending with -----END CERTIFICATE----- without any public or private key in between.

Comment: "can't connect to the server" is not really clear. Do you have an error message? If so, which one? A timeout instead? Etc.

Comment: Safari simply says "Safari can't connect to the server 'localhost'" and "Safari can't connect to the server 'www.ocetace.net'".

Comment: What do your logfiles say? Did you try other clients, `wget`,  `curl`, `openssl s_client`, etc. both locally and remotely? Did you try online website testing HTTPS? etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to put line-feeds comments. The system log repeats the following:

`Aug 14 18:41:06 jnorrisMM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd[18660]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1`
`Aug 14 18:41:06 jnorrisMM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.`
`Aug 14 18:41:16 jnorrisMM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd[18667]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1`

Comment: Please look up at the question--I added the system.log error messages at the end of the question.

Comment: Look at Apache logfiles. The one quoted is just from the system starting Apache, telling you it was not able in fact to start Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you uncommented this line "#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" and your server worked on port 80 then you don't need 2nd VirtualHost conf for port 80 because it's already configured in some file. Also in  you don't need to add SSL Engine ON and certificates.

After you clear this, you should focus on your certificates. You have 2 certs and 1 key (private) that matches 1 of your certs which is use to secure server.

This file /private/etc/apache2/ocetacea_bundle.crt is bundle and may contain more then 1 certificate inside of it not the keys.

Configuration seems fine, and you are almost there since Syntax is OK. Also make sure you open port 443 in your firewall before accessing it outside.

Best regards

Comment: I commented out the <VirtualHost *:80> completely, and I still cannot connect to localhost or www.ocetacea.net.